# I want to stick the website header to the top of the page

Tags: header

I assume that adding position: fixed and top:0 and left:0 to the header class it would work. instead the header sticks to the left of the page.

here is the HTML:

```html
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="header">header</div>
      <div id="content">
        <div class="product-container">
          <div class="product-picture-container">
            <img src="pic/product1.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="product-info-container">
            <p>Black and Gray Athletic Cotton Socks - 6 Pairs</p>
          </div>
          <div class="product-rating-container">
            <img class="product-rating-stars" src="pic/rating1.png" alt="" />
            <label class="product-rating-count">87</label>
          </div>
          <div class="product-price-container"><p>$10.90</p></div>
          <div class="product-quantity-container">
            <select name="product-quantity" id="product-quantity-choices">
              <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <p class="product-color-text">Color</p>
          <div class="product-variation-container">
            <button class="product-variation-color-button">Green</button>
            <button class="product-variation-color-button">Black</button>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}

html {
  /* background-color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
  color: rgb(233, 233, 233); */
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

I tried to change it to position: sticky. but the header disappears in a certain point when scrolling down